# Why appending AutoFilter corrupts my excel file in this example?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Hi I use the below method to apply an AutoFilter :

```
public static void ApplyAutofilter(string fileName, string sheetName, string reference)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);
                var arrSheets = sheets as Sheet[] ?? sheets.ToArray();

                string relationshipId = arrSheets.First().Id.Value;
                var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

                var autoFilter = new AutoFilter() { Reference = reference };
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(autoFilter);

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
        }
```

And I have this simple Excel sheet:

[image]

The thing is when I call this method as:

```
ApplyAutofilter(@".\Test.xlsx", "Foo", "A0:A200");
```

or

```
ApplyAutofilter(@".\Test.xlsx", "Foo", "A1:A200");
```

The filter is not applied and the file becomes corrupted when I try to open it after:

[image]

QUESTION: Any idea how to apply this autofiler to an excel sheet without corrupting it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because of *where* you are writing the `autoFilter` element in the XML. I opened a file that I had run your code on and opened it in the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425). This showed that the error was

[image: Error message: Unexpected Child Element]

Looking at the ECMA-376 standard from [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) the XML for a `Worksheet` looks like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_Worksheet">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="sheetPr" type="CT_SheetPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dimension" type="CT_SheetDimension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetViews" type="CT_SheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetFormatPr" type="CT_SheetFormatPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cols" type="CT_Cols" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetData" type="CT_SheetData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetCalcPr" type="CT_SheetCalcPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetProtection" type="CT_SheetProtection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="protectedRanges" type="CT_ProtectedRanges" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="scenarios" type="CT_Scenarios" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="autoFilter" type="CT_AutoFilter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sortState" type="CT_SortState" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dataConsolidate" type="CT_DataConsolidate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="customSheetViews" type="CT_CustomSheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="mergeCells" type="CT_MergeCells" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="phoneticPr" type="CT_PhoneticPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="conditionalFormatting" type="CT_ConditionalFormatting" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="dataValidations" type="CT_DataValidations" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="hyperlinks" type="CT_Hyperlinks" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="printOptions" type="CT_PrintOptions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="pageMargins" type="CT_PageMargins" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="pageSetup" type="CT_PageSetup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="headerFooter" type="CT_HeaderFooter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="rowBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="colBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="customProperties" type="CT_CustomProperties" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cellWatches" type="CT_CellWatches" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="ignoredErrors" type="CT_IgnoredErrors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="smartTags" type="CT_SmartTags" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="drawing" type="CT_Drawing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="drawingHF" type="CT_DrawingHF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="picture" type="CT_SheetBackgroundPicture" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="oleObjects" type="CT_OleObjects" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="controls" type="CT_Controls" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="webPublishItems" type="CT_WebPublishItems" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="tableParts" type="CT_TableParts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="extLst" type="CT_ExtensionList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Notice that it's a `sequence` so the order of the items matters. In my sample file above the `autoFilter` element was added after the `pageMargins` element which is contrary to the above schema.

Changing the code to write the `autoFilter` element to the correct place fixes your code. I'm not sure if this is the most effecient way but this should work. It is essentially working backwards up the child elements of the `workbook` until it finds the first element that the `autoFilter` can be after. Once it finds that it uses the `InsertAfter` method to insert the `autoFilter` into the correct place:

```
public static void ApplyAutofilter(string fileName, string sheetName, string reference)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);
        var arrSheets = sheets as Sheet[] ?? sheets.ToArray();

        string relationshipId = arrSheets.First().Id.Value;
        var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

        var autoFilter = new AutoFilter() { Reference = reference };
        OpenXmlElement preceedingElement = GetPreceedingElement(worksheetPart);
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(autoFilter, preceedingElement);

        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
    }
}

public static OpenXmlElement GetPreceedingElement(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
{
    List<Type> elements = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(Scenarios),
        typeof(ProtectedRanges),
        typeof(SheetProtection),
        typeof(SheetCalculationProperties),
        typeof(SheetData)
    };

    OpenXmlElement preceedingElement = null;
    foreach (var item in worksheetPart.Worksheet.ChildElements.Reverse())
    {
        if (elements.Contains(item.GetType()))
        {
            preceedingElement = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    return preceedingElement;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice! this works! It helped me to solve my problem. Using the following made the difference

```
OpenXmlElement preceedingElement = GetPreceedingElement(worksheetPart);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(autoFilter, preceedingElement);
```