# OpenXML corrupts excel file when I set a pageSetup

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a excel file created with DevExpress from my program. I need to add horizontal break page in this file but I can't because my DevExpress version does not handle it. So I use OpenXML in a separate class to retrieve the generated excel file in order to add it horizontal break page.

After the DevExpress generation, my file looks like this :
[image]

So it has 6 pages. I'd like to have this instead of:
[image]

In order to print each tab on a separate sheet.

So I used PageSetup from openXML to define the width and height of my excel file :

```
private void InsertPageBreaks()
{
    //uint columnIndex = 17U;
    uint rowIndex = 42;

    SpreadsheetDocument sd = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("c:\\temp\\ExcelExport1.xlsx", true);
    try
    {

        WorkbookPart workbookPart = sd.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Last();

        // Uncomment the following line to insert row page breaks.
        InsertHorizontalPageBreak(rowIndex, worksheetPart);

        PageSetup pageSetup = new PageSetup() {FitToHeight = 2, FitToWidth = 1};
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(pageSetup);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (sd != null)
            ((IDisposable)sd).Dispose();
    }
}
```

But after processing, when I try to open the file an error is showing up "Sorry we found a problem with some content [...]".

Do you guys have any idea how to help me ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without seeing the file but I'm pretty sure this is happening because of the order of your elements.

The [ECMA-376 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) defines the schema for an Excel document, part of which is the `Worksheet` definition (page 3900). The definition is too large to paste here in its entirety but the section regarding the `PageSetup` looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name = "pageMargins" type="CT_PageMargins" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "pageSetup" type="CT_PageSetup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "headerFooter" type="CT_HeaderFooter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "rowBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "colBreaks" type="CT_PageBreak" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "customProperties" type="CT_CustomProperties" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "cellWatches" type="CT_CellWatches" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "ignoredErrors" type="CT_IgnoredErrors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "smartTags" type="CT_SmartTags" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "drawing" type="CT_Drawing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "drawingHF" type="CT_DrawingHF" minOccurs="2222 0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "picture" type="CT_SheetBackgroundPicture" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "oleObjects" type="CT_OleObjects" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "controls" type="CT_Controls" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "webPublishItems" type="CT_WebPublishItems" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "tableParts" type="CT_TableParts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name = "extLst" type="CT_ExtensionList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

As the `Worksheet` is defined as a Sequence, the order is important. Looking at your screenshots it appears you have a `Header` which must come *after* the `PageSetup` but your code is adding the `PageSetup` to the end of the `Worksheet`.

For an example on how you can add items to the correct place, please see my answer to [Why appending AutoFilter corrupts my excel file in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398450/why-appending-autofilter-corrupts-my-excel-file-in-this-example/25410242#25410242)

Answer (score 1):

The OpenXML SDK provides a class called PageSetupProperties which provides a property called FitToPage.

Set this property to true in order to get the radio button selected:

```
SheetProperties _oPageSetupProperties = new SheetProperties(new PageSetupProperties());
newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties = _oPageSetupProperties;

// Set the FitToPage property to true
newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.PageSetupProperties.FitToPage = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);

//set fitto width and height
PageSetup pageSetup = new PageSetup();
pageSetup.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape;
pageSetup.FitToWidth = 1;
pageSetup.FitToHeight = 50;
newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(pageSetup);
```